# Why is this wine so expensive?

Tags: wine

Online, this wine is $400. At Cibo in Coral Gables, it's $2100.

Yep, $2100, sir. Don't forget the tip, ma'am.

Does this wine taste like white truffle? what's up?

https://www.wine-searcher.com/find/mouton+rothschild+pauillac+medoc+bordeaux+france/1993

Comment: Most restaurants mark up wine 3X retail. In this case it's 5X from an internet price. Sounds excessive to me but not uncommon. Mouton Rothschild is one of the greatest wine producers. It's expensive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several things going on.

1. Mouton Rothschild is on of the few "first growth" Bordeaux wineries. All of them are highly collectible. New bottles go for between $600 and $700 for Mouton Rothschild, from a quick glance around the internet, which is a jump in price from the bottle you are looking at.
2. 1993 wasn't the best vintage in Bordeaux, which is why the bottle price is lower for such an old wine. The 1995 vintage was much better and is selling for significantly more money
3. Why is it $2100 at Cibo? First restaurants mark up wine about 3x the retail price (even though they buy wines at wholesale). Five times the price is a little excessive for a wine that's probably not that great. Then sometimes restaurants will have that special extra expensive bottle just daring some high roller, that doesn't know anything about wine, to drop money on it. It's very common.